# How do I create a new user model in Django named student without modifying the already existing base user?

Tags: django, django-models

So in my academic management system when I want to modify the model student with fields like class and division but the base admin used that I create with create super user should remain the same . How to achieve this in Django ?

Comment: Don't create a new user model. Create a profile model with a one-to-one relation to User instead. See Django docs for different approaches for profile models.

Comment: [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Comment: Best tutorial I've seen on the various ways to extend the standard User model.  I'd recommend option 3 or 4 myself, depending on your requirements : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html